# Api calls chaining to some limit Rxjava2 + Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using `Retrofit2` with `Rxjava` to make API calls. I have to make multiple API calls ( of the same API ), let's say 100 of them. Now I want, at max 5 of them to be executed parallelly. So if 5 API calls are going on, 6th one should wait. As soon as any one of those ongoing 5 calls is completed, 6th one should start. I don't want this in bulk of 5 where first 5 completes and only after that next 5 happens.

I'm not sure how can I achieve with `Rxjava` and that's why I don't have any snippet to post. Any help would be great

Comment: What is the specific scenario you're dealing with? Rather than try and create this in RxJava I would look at the core problem, is this the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJava has certain operators that can limit the number of threads in action.

```
observable
  .flatMap( input -> apiCallReturningObservable( input ), 5 )
  .subscribe();
```

will have a maximum of 5 invocations of `apiCallReturningObservable()` at one time.

Comment: Will it call the sixth automatically when some of the five workers finishes or will it just cut off after the supplied limit?

Comment: The documentation says it eventually maps all the values, but puts a cap on the number of simultaneous subscriptions.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed!